# iPhone Core Data: Initializing Managed Object without a context

Tags: iphone, core-data

Is there a way to initialize a managed object outside of a context. I'm basically trying to alloc/init a Managed Object outside of a context first, then figure out if I really want to insert the object, and then inject it into the datastore using an existing managed object context.

Is this possible, or does it go against the intended usage of Core Data?

Answer (score 5):

Managed Object are "managed" by the context, therefore you cant really instanciate them with alloc since they are not meant to be.However, instantiating a managed object through the context does not persist it until you call save method on the context, so you would have the same effect using the context to instanciate it and  only saving after you figure out that you really want to use the object.

Comment: I figured as much, just wanted to confirm that this was the case. Thank you Daniel.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot instantiate an `NSManagedObject` instsance outside of an `NSManagedObjectContext` (well, you can, but bad things will happen and your program will almost certainly not work as you'd hoped). You can, however, create an `NSInMemoryPersistentStore`-backed `NSManagedObjectContext`. It's slightly more setup (not much) and everything vanishes when you dealloc the in-memory store. In the mean time, you get all the benefits of Core Data's object graph management.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who stumbles upon this question, here's how I accomplished what the OP was probably going for:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = AppDelegate.managedObjectContext;
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyModel"
    inManagedObjectContext:moc];
MyModel *model = [[MyModel alloc] initWithEntity:entity
    insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];
```

Comment: I would be wary of using this if the MOCs are created using anything but the default NSConfinementConcurrencyType -- NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType or NSMainQueueConcurrencyType may lead to issues with properties getting nil'ed

Comment: Also, `awakeFromInsert` is not invoked!

Comment: ```awakeFromInsert``` will be invoked if you later add it to the MOC via ```[moc insertObject:model];```

Comment: Unsure about the concurrency settings you mentioned though, good point

Comment: I can't say for sure what's niling my attributes.   Could also be that [super awakeFromInsert] is what's doing it... nonetheless, the point is this method has some gotchas, even if it did seem to work for me in a single context.

Answer (score 0):

What you are probably shooting for is multiple contexts. You can create an additional "scratchpad" context and then merge any changes back into the main context. One of Apple's iPhone sample projects accomplishes this exact thing. You'll have to log into the dev center to find it.